# How to toggle between indentations on emacs?

Tags: emacs

emacs n00b here.

I face this problem at least once a week, I have a function call with its arguments one per line, but I'd like to reformat that such that all the arguments go to one line, i.e. I want to go from:

```
f(
  x,
  y,
  z
);
```

to:

```
f(x, y, z);
```

what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Put point on the `);` line, then press `M-^` 4 times; alternatively, press `M-^` once followed by `C-x z z z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I doubt that it is the best way to do it but I wrote a function anyways. So here it goes:

```lisp
(defun format-args-column-to-inline()
  "Takes a c-style function whose arguments listed one per line and puts them inline."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line 1)
  (re-search-forward "(")
  (forward-char -1)
  (let ((start (point)))
    (save-restriction
      (save-excursion
        (forward-sexp 1)
        (narrow-to-region start (point)))
      (while (re-search-forward "$")
        (progn
          (delete-forward-char 1)
          (just-one-space 1))))))
```

Put your cursor somewhere in the first line and call the function.

**Edit:** Just saw that you wanted something *slightly* different. The output of this function is `f( x, y, z );` [note the trailing and leading space of the argument list].

Answer (score 6):

In general, a simple approach to custom reformatting requirements is to create a keyboard macro which does the required editing in a generic way.

Abilities like moving across sexps & balanced expressions, searching and replacing within regions, and narrowing and widening the buffer all make this sort of thing pretty straightforward.

You can then give the macro a name, output its definition into your init file, and bind it to a key for future usage, all with no elisp knowledge required.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Keyboard Macros` <kbd>RET</kbd>

*Edit:* (for "Emacs n00bs" everywhere).

**DO** learn how to use keyboard macros. The learning curve is pretty shallow<sup>1</sup>, and they will pay amazing dividends in the long term.

Once you've learned how they work, *force* yourself to use them: Whenever you encounter a problem, say to yourself "Can I do this with a keyboard macro?" and if you think the answer is yes, then give it a try.

If you don't make yourself use them to begin with, you probably won't often think about them when use-cases crop up; but once they're a familiar part of your tool kit you'll find yourself using them *very* regularly.

<sup>1</sup> Shallow, but probably *longer* than you expect, as you gradually come to realise just how much you can actually accomplish with the things. My own moment of clarity came when it occurred to me that I wasn't restricted to a single buffer, and correlating/extracting/transforming data from multiple buffers was something I could automate *easily*.

And of course macros can do anything that you can do, so their power grows with your own knowledge of Emacs.